# Refactor by using argparse options

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, argparse

Trying to clean this up to have the times passed in as parameters through argparse and not sys. The idea is to take time parameters as input and search agains the bucket, converts them and return the matches. It works with the sys.argv values but this is is limited obviously. Trying to refactor by using argparse options.

you'll see that

start_time = sys.argv[3]
end_time = sys.argv[5]
are hardcoded

```
import argparse
import logging
import os
import sys
import re
import time

"""take CLI parameters and search against bucket, converts them and return matching dirs"""

FILE = 'bucket'
TIME_FORMAT = "%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S"

def get_file():
    """Get to dir, fetch resources"""
    s3 = resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(FILE)
    index = sys.argv[2]
    objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=index)
    return objects


def convert_index():
    """conversion of the epoch filenames output
    """
    dir_files = get_file()
    for file in dir_files:
        output = file.key       # file is a class type
        if 'db_' in output:
            output_dir = output.split('/') 
            times = output_dir              # [1] is index name only
            start_time = sys.argv[3]
            end_time = sys.argv[5]
            fields = times[2].split('_')
            try:
                start = convert_epoch(fields[1])     # first time field
                end = convert_epoch(fields[2])       # second time field
                if start.startswith(start_time) or end.startswith(start_time) == start_time:
                    print("{}\t\t is {}_{}".format(output, start, end))
                    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='logfile.log', format='%(asctime)s - \
                                                                                           %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
                elif end.startswith(end_time) or end.startswith(end_time) == end_time:
                    print("{}\t\t\t is {}_{}".format(output, start, end))
            except ValueError as ve:
                    logging.info("did not convert due to {}".format(ve))



def convert_epoch(input_epoch):
    """takes epoch value and converts to human readable
   time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime(1442530758))
   '09-17-2019_15-59-18'
   """
    converted_epoch_value = time.strftime(TIME_FORMAT, time.localtime(int(input_epoch)))
    return converted_epoch_value


def main():
    parser: ArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      description="""Supply the directory you want to search files for. Give earliest and latest time to query bucket for
         usage: format_files.py [-h] [-e --earliest] [-l --latest]""")
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--index', required=False, help='index name directory to query for ex:\n'
                                                              'format_files.py -i folder/folder')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--start_time', required=False, help='queries from start time (not necessarily earliest time)')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--end_time', required=False, help='queries data until end time (not necessarily latest time)')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.exit(parser.description)

    if args.index:
        convert_index()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running into issues in the if start.startswith(start_time) or end.startswith(start_time) == start_time:
line when trying to pass in argparse options for the times

any insight is appreciated

Comment: `start_time=args.start_time` etc

Comment: Clean up your code.  You shouldn't need to use `sys.argv` if you aleady parsing the input with `argparse`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a removed a lot of complexity to the code to show your a simple proof of concept:

```
import argparse

def convert_index(args):
    start_time = args.start_time
    end_time = args.end_time

    start = '09-17-2015_15-59-18'
    end = '12-01-2019_15-59-18'
    if start.startswith(start_time) or end.startswith(start_time) == start_time:
        print('starts with start_time')
    elif end.startswith(end_time) or end.startswith(end_time) == end_time:
        print('starts with end_time')

def main():
    parser: ArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--start_time', required=False, help='queries from start time (not necessarily earliest time)')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--end_time', required=False, help='queries data until end time (not necessarily latest time)')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    convert_index(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

->

```
$ python3 test.py  -s 09-17-2015 -e 12-01-2019
starts with start_time
```

Comment: appreciate it, I think I was overcomplicating it in my function

Comment: @zendannyy you are welcome, can you please accept my answer as the correct answer if it solved your issue